# How to find (and replace) words with capital letters from a string?

Tags: php, string, replace

```
$string = "WORD is the first HEJOU is the Second BOOM is the Third";
$sring = str_replce('???', '???<br>', $string);
echo $string; // <br>WORD is the first <br>HEJOU is the Second <br>BOOM is the Third
```

Well the illustration speaks for itself. I want to select all words with capital letters (not words that start with capital letter) and replace with something in front of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = "WORD is the first HEJOU is the Second BOOM is the Third";
$string = preg_replace("#\b([A-Z]+)\b#", "<br>\\1", $string);
echo $string;
```

**OUTOUT**
`<br>WORD is the first <br>HEJOU is the Second <br>BOOM is the Third`

The regular expression being used says:

```
\b - Match a word boundary, zero width
[A-Z]+ - Match any combination of capital letters 
\b - Match another word boundary
([A-Z]+) - Capture the word for use in the replacement
```

Then, in the replacement

```
\\1, replace with the captured group.
```

Comment: It is just a delimiter.  The '#' can be replaced by another character.  / is common. I just always seem to use #

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` just replace specific string to other specific one. You may use `preg_replace`

```
print preg_replace('~\b[A-Z]+\b~','<br>\\0',$string);
```

Comment: I think you mean to replace with back reference to `\\1` not `\\0`, which matches the whole input.

Comment: @sberry as you can see no \1 in my regexp. \\0 is full MATCHED regexp. And it works

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php